# mathabx + mathtools -> extremely odd underbrace behaviour... how to fix?

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

This following code produce very strange result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$$W_n(\underbrace{\mbox{\textvisiblespace},
                  \mbox{\textvisiblespace},
                  \dots,
                  \mbox{\textvisiblespace}
                 }_n 
     )
$$
\end{document}
```

If I just remove one of `mathabx` or `mathtools` the brace is displayed normally. Any ideas?

P.S. I use some symbols from `mathabx` and some commands from `mathtools` in the book, so I probably need both packages...

Comment: `mathabx` has wider effects that aren't always predicted.  maybe using just the particular symbols you need, and not loading the entire package, would get rid of this problem (not tried).  good advice at the question [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sure, I see, probably it would be the best way.

Comment: On a side note, no need to load both `amsmath` and `mathtools`. Former is loaded by latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mathabx` has wider effects that aren't always predicted. maybe using just the particular symbols you need, and not loading the entire package,
would get rid of this problem (not tried).

good advice can be found at the question
[Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579)

Comment: I'd prefer this way since `mathabx` produces some more strange behaviour if loaded later too, looks like `relsize` doesn't work as expected. Extracting required fonts and symbols was easy and works perfect.

Answer (score 17):

use it the other way round:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
```

Comment: @Nick Note that it's not `mathtools`, but `amsmath` that redefines `\underbrace`. You'd get the same with loading `mathabx` before `amsmath`.

Answer (score 3):

Mathtools redefines `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`, which leads to problems with some fonts. To access the original definitions, use `\LaTeXunderbrace` and `\LaTeXoverbrace`, respectively.