# Adding vertical arrow+math formula over equal sign

Tags: equations, arrows

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to adding avertical arrow and a math formula over equal sign. The arrow's height should be changed also in a confortable way.

On Tex Stack Exchange I found only how add text over equal sign.

[image]

Thank you so much for your willingness.

EDIT: the goal is to write equations over each equal signs which occur in a chain of relationships; a=b=c=d=e=f...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,mathtools}
\newcommand{\equparrow}[1][1]{\stackrel{\text{\scalebox{1}[#1]{$\uparrow$}}}{=}}
\newcommand{\equparrowx}[2][1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{#2}}{\equparrow[#1]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
b&=a/c\\[-.5\baselineskip]
a&\equparrow b\\[-.5\baselineskip]
a&\equparrow[2] \frac12
\end{align*}
\[a\equparrowx{a=b/c}b\]
\[a\equparrowx[1.5]{a=b/c}b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @tomacs, if possible I'd like to write the equation over = with smaller dimension.

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi  - More exactly?

Comment: I changed the figure. Sorry for my mistake....I edited your figure accidentally.

Comment: I edited my solution!

Comment: Beautiful solution @tomacs. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\newcommand{\eqstackrel}[1]{\stackrel{\substack{\mathclap{#1}\\[0.5ex]\displaystyle\uparrow\\ ~}}{ = } }

\begin{document}

    \[ a\eqstackrel{b = a/c} b \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: also your solution is very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

For those who do not want to use mathtools (e.g. because [underbrace looks strange then](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117628/mathabx-mathtools-extremely-odd-underbrace-behaviour-how-to-fix)), you can exchange `\mathclap` by `\ensuremath`. I also changed `uparrow` to `downarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\eqstackrel}[1]{\stackrel{\substack{\ensuremath{#1} \\ [0.5ex] \displaystyle \downarrow \\ ~}}{ = } }

\begin{document}

    \[ a\eqstackrel{b = a/c} b \]%

\end{document}
```

(adapted from @Bernard's answer)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be using a commutative diagram like `xy` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1.3pc{\scriptstyle{a=b/c}&\\
a=b \ar[u]&}
\end{document}
```

The vertical arrow can be increase or decrease from the parameter `1.3`.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Sebastiano thank you very much for your solution

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Hi Gennaro my best regards from Sicily :-)